# javascript alert with multiline string from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my site I need to create an alert with multiline text in it.
the alert text is exported from a database function (string) and is like :

```
BMW - (3 items) \nTOYOTA - (5 items) \nOPEL - (10 items) \n
```

The javascript code that I'am using to build the alert is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function showAlert(myVar) {
        window.alert(myVar);
}

</script>
```

But the alert that I'm getting is one line instead of the expected multiline (with the use of the \n)
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). In the normal course of things, `alert("foo\nbar")` shows an alert with `foo` on one line and `bar` on another.

Comment: `\n` works fine for me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZLadz

Comment: Sounds like your debugging has a false assumption somewhere.  `\n` does indeed result in a new line in a browser `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text value between quotes ":

"BMW - (3 items) \nTOYOTA - (5 items) \nOPEL - (10 items) \n"

Try to do it on Chrome console, I'm sure that it will work:

```
alert("BMW - (3 items) \nTOYOTA - (5 items) \nOPEL - (10 items) \n");
```